# OSError 24 (Too many open files) when reading bunch of FITS with astropy.io

Tags: python, fits, astropy

I’m trying to load into memory a few 2 000 FITS using `astropy.io.fits`:

```
def readfits(filename):
    with fits.open(filename) as ft:
        # the fits contain a single HDU
        data = ft[0].data
    return data

data_sci = []
for i in range(2000):
    data_sci.append(readfits("filename_{}.fits".format(i)))
```

However, when reaching the 1015th file, `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open
files` is raised.

I have the same issue with:

```
def readfits(filename):
    ft = fits.open(filename) as ft:
    data = ft[0].data
    ft.close()
    return data
```

I suspect that `astropy.io.fits` does not properly close the file. Is there a
way I can force the files to be closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `readfits` function actually leaves the file handle open in order to keep access to the data, because by default it creates a [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) to the data and does not read it entirely into physical memory, as explained: http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#i-m-opening-many-fits-files-in-a-loop-and-getting-oserror-too-many-open-files

Incidentally, if you just want a function that reads the data out of the first HDU this is already built in: http://docs.astropy.org/en/v1.0.5/io/fits/api/files.html#astropy.io.fits.getdata

It's not necessary to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

After taking a look at the astropy documentation i found this: http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#i-m-opening-many-fits-files-in-a-loop-and-getting-oserror-too-many-open-files

Comment: Thanks, this was the info I was searching for! The solution I used was a bit different though: as I needed to keep the data in memory, I couldn’t blindly use `del`. I simply replaced the line `data = ft[0].data` with `data = ft[0].data.copy()` instead.

Comment: If you do `data.copy()` then you're loading the entire data into memory anyways, so you might as well just open the files with `memmap=False` and then there's no issue.

Also if the data consists of tables there was an issue, now fixed, that resulted in a resource leak.

Comment: @Iguananaut, definitely buying that `memmap=False`. I should have read more carefully the doc of `open`…

Comment: It's a tricky thing; easy to miss. Opening lots of files simultaneously is not the most common case, but it's common enough that there should probably be a better interface for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function and store its output as long as you have memory. I thought it worths mentioning the answer explicitly but the credit goes to [Iguananaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982257/iguananaut), [bkaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5410228/bkaf), and [this page](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#i-m-opening-many-fits-files-in-a-loop-and-getting-oserror-too-many-open-files).

```
def get_single_fits_data(fits_dir):

    hdul  = fits.open(fits_dir)
    for hdu in hdul:
        image_data = hdu.data.copy()
    hdul.close()
    gc.collect()

    return image_data
```